# Is there any evidence that environmental enrichment enchances executive functioning in humans?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

By environmental enrichment, I mean a cognitively, socially and environmentally stimulating environment.  Most of the studies I discovered were tested on animals, in which the answer is a resounding yes.  But is there anything that suggests this enhances executive functioning in humans?

To clarify, there is probably evidence that a deprived environment, such as isolation and poorly constructed childhood homes (Romanian orphanages comes to mind), aren't particularly good for executive functioning.  I'm more looking for evidence that enriched environments improves cognition.  For example, would traveling overseas, or learning a new skill, increase brainpower?

Comment: "Cognitive functioning" is far too broad (for instance it includes language), so the answer is a trivial yes. Do you mean IQ given that you say "brainpower" in your last sentence?

Comment: Probably something more in line with executive functioning, like attention, memory, etc.  I changed the question accordingly.